# JS Countdown Timer from PHP variable (AJAX)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

The script below returns time since the last customer registered in minutes and seconds. The variable of registration date is pulled from the separate PHP file.

How to combine the two to get a dynamic result (AJAX) as soon as new customer registers.

The script below works well, but only updates on reload.

**index.php**

```
<?php
    require_once('get_file.php')
?>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
var currenttime = <?php print json_encode($todaysDate, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES) ?>;
var lastsale = <?php print json_encode($orderCreated, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES) ?>;

var montharray=new Array("01","02","03","04","05","06","07","08","09","10","11","12")
var serverdate=new Date(currenttime)
var lastordercreated=new Date(lastsale)

function padlength(what){
    var output=(what.toString().length==1)? "0"+what : what
    return output
}

function displaytime(){
    serverdate.setSeconds(serverdate.getSeconds()+1)

    // Todays Date
    var datestring=padlength(serverdate.getDate())+"/"+montharray[serverdate.getMonth()]+"/"+serverdate.getFullYear()

    // Current Time
    var timestring=padlength(serverdate.getHours())+":"+padlength(serverdate.getMinutes())+":"+padlength(serverdate.getSeconds())

    // Last Ordered Count
    var lastorderedcount=padlength(serverdate.getTime()) - padlength(lastordercreated.getTime())

    var minutes = Math.floor((lastorderedcount % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
    var seconds = Math.floor((lastorderedcount % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);
    var lastordercountdown = minutes+":"+seconds

    // Output
    document.getElementById("todaysdate").innerHTML=datestring
    document.getElementById("currenttime").innerHTML=timestring
    document.getElementById("lastordered").innerHTML=lastordercountdown

}   

function updateAjax() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'getLastData.php',
        success: function(res) {
            currenttime         = res.currentDate;
            lastsale            = res.orderCreated;
            serverdate          = new Date(currenttime);
            lastordercreated    = new Date(lastsale);
            console.log(res);
        }
    });
}

window.onload=function(){
setInterval('displaytime()', 1000)
setInterval(updateAjax, 1000)
}
</script>

<span id="lastordercountdown"></span>
```

**getLastData.php**

```
<?php
    require_once('get_data.php');

    print json_encode([
        'currentDate' => $todaysDate,
        'orderCreated' => $orderCreated
    ],JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
?>
```

Comment: Are you asking how to do a raw ajax request? Right now, I see no AJAX anywhere. Are we doing this without the help of any libraries, or can we use jQuery?

Comment: How is this [tag:ajax] or even [tag:jquery] related? You print out an integer with PHP for time and increment it with javascript each second doing a date format on it.

Comment: The jQuery is pulled but I have no experience in using AJAX. As long as the id element gets updated dynamically, any lib can be included.

Comment: Ideally the request to PHP would be upon change of JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With jQuery, you could do something like this:

getLastCustomer.php:

```
<?php
    require_once('get_file.php')
?>

echo json_encode(['currentDate' => $todaysDate, 'lastRegistered' => $lastRegistered]);
```

Your main script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var currenttime = '<?php print (json_encode($todaysDate)) ?>'
var lastregistered = <?php print (json_encode($lastRegistered)) ?>

var montharray=new Array("01","02","03","04","05","06","07","08","09","10","11","12")
var serverdate=new Date(currenttime)
var registrationdate=new Date(lastregistered)

function padlength(what){
    var output=(what.toString().length==1)? "0"+what : what
    return output
}

function displaytime(){
    serverdate.setSeconds(serverdate.getSeconds()+1)


    // Last Registration Countdown
    var lastregcount=padlength(serverdate.getTime()) - padlength(registrationdate.getTime())

    var minutes = Math.floor((lastregcount % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
    var seconds = Math.floor((lastregcount % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);
    var lastregcountdown = minutes+":"+seconds

    document.getElementById("registrationcount").innerHTML=lastregcountdown

}   

function updateAjax() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'getLastCustomer.php',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(res) {
            currenttime      = res.currentDate;
            lastregistered   = res.lastRegistered;
            serverdate       = new Date(currenttime);
            registrationdate = new Date(lastregistered)
        }
    });
}        

window.onload=function(){
    setInterval(displaytime, 1000)
    setInterval(updateAjax, 30 * 1000)
}
</script>
```

Comment: Is there anything missing from this as am getting invalid format date as: NaN/undefined/NaN

Comment: Add some `console.log`'s in the success function, and see what's being returned from the server. Are the correct datetimes being set?

Comment: The output of JSON is: {"currentDate":"03/03/2017 13:01:33"}{"lastRegistered":"03/03/2017 13:00:58"} and the file does reload well.

Comment: The missing piece from $.ajax was:dataType:"json",

Comment: Updated @damek132

Comment: Would you have any idea how do would I go about implementing check on value change like this:   var previous = null;
    var current = null;
    setInterval(function() {
        $.getJSON("data.json", function(json) {
            current = JSON.stringify(json);            
            if (previous && current && previous !== current) {
                console.log('refresh');
                location.reload();
            }
            previous = current;
        });                       
    }, 2000);